# .Net framework is not supporting

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I try to open Visual studio it says "This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET framework: .NET framework version=v4.5". But I already have installed .NET framework version v4.8.1? (This used to work fine and I've worked with .NET until I did an update to my PC the other day)

Since Visual studio was not opening I deleted Installer folder. But when I tried to reinstall it, it gives the above error message

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net45

Comment: Also support for Net4.5 ended in 2016 - that's nine years ago. Maybe time to think about moving to a supported release?

Comment: "This used to work fine and I've worked with .NET until I did an update to my PC the other day" doesn't look real. No update removes .NET Framework 4.5 SDK from a machine as far as I know. More likely you never installed that and it never works on this machine.

Comment: @LexLi I realy did a React, .Net project and the problem is my evaluation is coming soon but here i'm unable to even open Visual Studio now